# Repository pattern - how to use using

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm new to repository pattern/unit of work.
I used the [GitHub-timschreiber DapperUnitOfWork](https://github.com/timschreiber/DapperUnitOfWork) here and adjust it to my data.

I use WinForms. First I load my Form an load all data to dataGridView. Then I want to use da textBox to filter data. Everything works well.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Test();
    }

    void Test()
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(AppConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = uow.ProductRepository.GetAll();
        }

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(AppConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            var filteredList = uow.ProductRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Ident.Contains(textBox1.Text)).ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredList;
        }
    }
```

Now my question: Is this the right way to make use of it?
I mean for every action I need a using for the DB.
So is it correct or what is the right way?

Comment: Is this .Net Core (so .Net 3.1, 5.0 or 6.0)? If so you would be better of using Dependency Injection.

Comment: And how to use Dependency Injection??
Does this mean I have to rewrite my project code?

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection. There are lots of examples to be found.